# Find date between dates

Tags: sqlite, date

I want to insert dates in my (SQLLite) database (format: yyyyMMdd). 
This dates shouldn't overlap the same time.

I tried to use this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM termine WHERE string = "" AND ((startDay BETWEEN 20151007 AND 20151009) OR (endDay BETWEEN 20151007 AND 20151009))
```

Problem: If the database contains values like startDay = 20151006 and endDay = 20151010, my method won't work, because the dates are not between the others.

So, what is the easiest way to check if a date is in the range of another?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by *This dates shoudln't overlap the same time.*?

Comment: Of course. You have a period of time (e.g. 20151006 to 20151008). Now I have a seconds period oft time (e.g. 20151005 to 201251009). In this example the second overlaps the first perdiod of time and this is what I want to detect. My code only works if the second period of time is beetween the first (e.g.20151006-20151007).